# What is the difference between \fboxsep=1cm and \setlength{\fboxsep}{1cm}?

Tags: macros, lengths, syntax

Question has been written above.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

TeX notation versus LaTeX notation.

`\newdimen\myDim \myDim=5cm+\linewidth`  does not work

`\newdimen\myDim \myDim=\dimexpr5cm+\linewidth\relax`  works with `etex`

`\newlength\myLen \setlength\myLen{5cm+\linewidth}` works with package `calc`

`\newlength\myLen \setlength\myLen{\dimexpr5cm+\linewidth}` works with `etex`

`myDim=5cm plus 1em` does not work, must be a skip instead `\newskip\mySkip`

`\setlength\myLen{5cm plus 1em minus .2ex}` works, a LaTeX length is always a skip register

Comment: thanks for this answer. I will revisit this tomorrow again. It is a bit confusing to read. It is time to sleep. :-)

Answer (score 15):

To elaborate a bit on what Herbert says, LaTeX 'lengths' are what TeX calls 'skips': lengths with a rubber component. They can therefore be set using the TeX syntax

```
\fboxsep=1 cm
```

or the LaTeX syntax

```
\setlength{\fboxsep}{1 cm}
```

There are a couple of points to watch here. First, LaTeX inserts a `\relax` to prevent the code accidentally picking up a 'plus' or 'minus' part. For example

```
\def\Oops#1{\fboxsep=#1}
\Oops{1 cm} plus some space
```

will lead TeX is complain that a number is missing, as the 'plus' is interpreted as a stretch component for the skip. The LaTeX solution, which inserts a `\relax`, is safe. The same can of course be done in TeX macros without LaTeX:

```
\def\Safe#1{\fboxsep=#1\relax}
\Safe{1 cm} plus some space
```

Here the 'plus' is not mis-interpreted.

Herbert also points out that the `calc` package allows calculations as part of the length setting. Personally, I tend to use e-TeX for this:

```
\def\Safer#1{\fboxsep\glueexpr#1\relax}
```

In this, the calculation is done by the engine, which is usually a better plan than using macros. (Note though that `\glueexpr` only does basic arithmetic using `(`, `)`, `+`, `-`, `x` and `/`. The `calc` package has 'max' and 'min' functions.)

Comment: @Celdor Just a typo