# Plain TeX vs. LaTeX Macros

Tags: macros, plain-tex

I was wondering what's the (advantage) of doing something one way over the other in different systems. For instance, I read that users of plain TEX should use `\def` whenever they want to create a new command rather than using `\(re)newcommand` in LaTeX, and `dimen` assignments whenever they want to set lengths to something rather than using `\setlength`. I was just wanting to know the reasons for this, because I use `LaTeX2e`, but I tend to choose `\def` over using `\(re)newcommand` or `\newcommand`. To be more clear, I am looking for an explanation similar to the case of using `\(...\)` and `\[...\]` over `$...$` and `$$...$$` respectively.

Comment: Duplicate for the `\def` part: [macros - What is the difference between \def and \newcommand](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/655/2693). Duplicate for the `\setlength` part: [What is the difference between \fboxsep=1cm and \setlength{\fboxsep}{1cm}](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7784/2693)

Comment: @AlanMunn: Not so fast. It is not a duplicate I think at all. I am not asking for the difference between them in what their functionality provides. I am more specifically asking why would one use one over the other. Hence, using `\def` in plain TeX and using `\newcommand` in LaTeX. A question that could arise maybe, why can't one use either or for what platform they are working with? And sure, one probably can use either or (I never used plain-TeX), but there must be an advantage using one over the other depending on which platform you use.

Comment: Well the first answer linked mentions advantages and disadvantages of both (e.g. checking if defined (`\newcommand`); delimited arguments (`\def`)).  Maybe less so for the lengths commands.  Maybe you could clarify your question based on the answers given there, then?

Comment: Given your comment below, the answer is simple: `\newcommand` and `\setlength` are not defined in plain TeX, so plain TeX users must use `\def` etc.  LaTeX users can use both, since `\def` etc. are defined in the TeX language, and not specifically part of the plain format. So the choice is either/or for LaTeX users, but not for plain TeX users.

Comment: Alan: Thanks, that was even a more simple response than I expected.

Comment: Ok.  I'll turn the comments into an answer so that we can clear this question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First some terminology: Plain TeX and LaTeX are *formats* (sets of macros written in the TeX language.)  The LaTeX format provides many new commands which are only available to LaTeX users and are not available to plain TeX users.  Among these are the commands `\newcommand` and `\setlength`.  For a list of some of the common correspondences see:

- [List of higher-level LaTeX commands corresponding to TeX commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26742/list-of-higher-level-latex-commands-corresponding-to-tex-commands/26922#26922)

Any command which is defined as part of the TeX language itself can be used in either the plain TeX format or LaTeX.  However, the converse is not so: commands that are defined in LaTeX cannot be used in plain TeX.  So plain TeX users *must* use `\def`, while LaTeX users can use either `\def` or `\newcommand`.  However, there are some differences between the two:

- [What is the difference between \def and \newcommand?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/655/what-is-the-difference-between-def-and-newcommand)

On the differences between the length commands see:

- [What is the difference between \fboxsep=1cm and \setlength{\fboxsep}{1cm}?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7784/2693)

Answer (score 7):

- `\newcommand` prevents us from accidently overriding the existing command. `\def` does not provide this compile-checking.
- `\def` can accommodate more general delimiters for arguments such as `\def\point(#1,#2){\ensuremath{(#1,#2)}}`.

Comment: Thanks. But I am looking for an answer as to why a `plain-TeX` user is suggested to use `\def` over using `\newcommand` and also `dimen` over `\setlength`. Not necessarily what they do when compiled.

Answer (score 6):

For someone that knows LaTeX and having the choice between `\def` or `\newcommand`, there should be zero difference. That is, the difference is probably subjective/left up to personal preference. LaTeX *defines* `\newcommand` in terms of `\def`. As such, `\newcommand` merely provides a user-friendly and therefore slightly restricted interface to defining a macro.

Using `\newcommand` has the built-in safety of not being able to redefine a macro. For this, one should use `\renewcommand`. Alternatively, `\providecommand` can be used to define a new command; it defaults to `\newcommand` if the command does not exist, or discards its arguments if the command already exists (no redefinition).