# Latex to pdf is not working

Tags: pdftex

I created a simple tex file: sample1.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  Hello World!
\end{document}
```

I used command:

```
pdftex sample1.tex
```

log file is:

```
This is pdfTeXk, Version 3.141592-1.40.3 (Web2C 7.5.6) (format=pdftex 2013.10.9)  17 MAR 2016 18:50

entering extended mode
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**sample1.tex
(./sample1.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \documentclass
                  {article}
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.2 \begin
          {document}
? 
[1{/usr/share/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] )</usr/share/texmf/fon
ts/type1/bluesky/cm/cmr10.pfb>

Output written on sample1.pdf (1 page, 6933 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 10 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 131072)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Output pdf is as:
article document Hello World!

Results are not as expected

Comment: you are using plain tex not latex, use the command `pdflatex`

Comment: what is difference between plain and latex

Comment: @SanchayKumar -- you might get some help from this answer: [Plain TeX vs. LaTeX Macros](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35570/579)