# "\setlength" vs "equal"

Tags: syntax, dimensions, setlength

This is a very general question. Apparently a duplicate of:

[Other than syntax what is the difference between \dimen0= and \setlength{}{}?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63050/other-than-syntax-what-is-the-difference-between-dimen0-and-setlength)

[What is the difference between \fboxsep=1cm and \setlength{\fboxsep}{1cm}?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7784/what-is-the-difference-between-fboxsep-1cm-and-setlength-fboxsep1cm)

In order to set lengths, in the documentation and in the various posts, the following syntax is used, where *x* is the target measure value:

```
\setlength{\lengthname}{x}
```

However, it is also possible to type, much more simply:

```
\lengthname=x
```

Is there any reason why the `\setlength` variant, while heavier, less convenient, is apparently widely favored?

Is there any difference with respect to the effect of either command, or potential restrictions?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    
    \noindent
    First Paragraph. 
    
    Second Paragraph.
    
    \setlength{\parindent}{3em}
    
    Third Paragraph.
    
    \parindent=5em
    
    Fourth Paragraph.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks like a duplicate. See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63050/other-than-syntax-what-is-the-difference-between-dimen0-and-setlength?rq=1 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7784/what-is-the-difference-between-fboxsep-1cm-and-setlength-fboxsep1cm?rq=1 I hope this answers your question. :)

Comment: Thanks! --------

Comment: I did not see anyone mention this in the linked posts, also `\parindent 5em` is a valid syntax (i.e. the `=` is optional), similar to the case with `\let`

Comment: @Udi Just like with penalties (\xpenalty10000)! But can the space be removed then? Does `\parindent5cm` work? Apparently yes! It becomes much lighter than `\setlength`, I think it is safe to use this simplified syntax inside a document.

Comment: Indeed...... :)

Comment: I wouldn't say it is 100% safe,if you don't know what you are doing. For example, if I would want to insert some horizontal space before the word `plus`, I would get into troubles with `yello \hskip 10pt plus blue gives the color green `. In this case you would need to add `\relax`, just as `\setlength` does.

Comment: @Udi Yes I saw that in the other post. I was assuming that this case was specific enough as to be safely overlooked ;)